# .htaccess URL Rewrite for specific file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up URL like www.example.com/username
for something like www.example.com/profile.php?name=username

I tried this in my .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,B,QSA]
```

but this makes it work for all the pages. I want this to work only when URL is like www.example.com/username but it works also for www.example.com/users.php

If users.php or any other .php file is opened then the rewrite rule should not be applicable to it.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rewrite condition on the request uri
which matches everything not ending in .php

e.g.: (not tested)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,B,QSA]
```

checking if the uri is actually a file was very popular with frameworks,
but it is slower than the string match ending with .php because every request apache needs to check if the file exists on disk.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,B,QSA]
```

Comment: how to redirect http to https alongwith this??

Comment: can you help me here?

Comment: You need a 2 part config, 1 vrtualhost on :80 which redirects everything to https, and one virtualhost on:443 with this config.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.example/$1 [R,L]